# Use of fission products for electricity generation

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity, nuclear-engineering

Why can't we use fissions products for electricity production ?

As far has I know fissions products from current nuclear power plants create enough 'waste' heat to boil water; and temperature decreases too slowly for an human life. So why can't we design a reactor to use this energy.

Comment: I assume that You mean spent fuel, right? Because actually the main role of fission products (or rather the energy emitted during fission) is to heat water and produce electricity.

Comment: I assume you already looked up the thermal output of the reactor waste (typically expressed in units of W/Kg) and decided that it was economically viable, right?

Comment: Yes. The wastes we are trying to put in the deep of the earth for long time.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus economically viable is a point of view, because waste already exists and we spend a lot of money to manage them.

Comment: Actual spent fuel form only couple % of the fuel rod. Many countries reprocess spent fuel rods to retrieve uranium which didn't burn out and use it again as a fuel. I can guarantee that this is much more economic.

Comment: Like MOX ? yes. But I ask about vitrify waste before we vitrify them. There is no other plan than put them deep in the earth/ocean/space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some "order-of-magnitude" arguments:

Quoting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decay_heat#Spent_fuel :

> After one year, typical spent nuclear fuel generates about 10 kW of decay heat per tonne, decreasing to about 1 kW/t after ten years

Now since this is heat, you can't convert it to electricity with 100% efficiency, the maximum possible efficiency is given by the [Carnot efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_efficiency#Carnot_efficiency) $\eta$:

$$
  \eta \le 1 - \dfrac{T_\mathrm{cold}}{T_\mathrm{hot}}
$$

where $T_\mathrm{hot}$ would be the temperature of the spent fuel rods (in Kelvin) and $T_\mathrm{cold}$ would be the temperature of a cold reservoir against which a generator would work. One would have to do another calculation what a reasonable temperature of the fuel rods would be (in practice they currently seem to be kept at [50 degrees C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spent_fuel_pool#Operation)).

With 'primary' fuel typically [55 Gigawatt days per tonne](http://www.world-nuclear.org/info/Nuclear-Fuel-Cycle/Introduction/Nuclear-Fuel-Cycle-Overview/) can be produced, i.e. a 1 Gigawatt powerplant would use 365.25 / 55 = 6.6 tonnes per year.

Even assuming you would be able to convert this to electricity with 100% efficiency and assuming an average 5 kilowatts per tonne over 10 years, this would yield about 18'000 Kilowatt days or 0.018 Gigawatt days, about **0.03%** of the primary energy production.

You'll also see from the Carnot efficiency above that higher temperatures imply a higher possible efficiency, i.e. if one can spend some energy to extract the still fissionable material to be used in a reactor again, that is likely to be more efficient in terms of electricity generation.

It's true on the other hand that [radioisotope thermoelectric generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator) (radioactive sources combined with thermocouples) have been used on satellite missions.

Comment: So the production per tonne could be about the same as a medium wind turbine. I have heard that radio-isotope thermoelectric generators are'nt popular because of security reason. End of life device need specials cares.